# Selection sort vs Bubble sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matplotlib, time-complexity

I am learning the time complexity of bubble sort and selection sort using Python. In theory selection sort is said to be faster than bubble sort ,however my programs written in Python
indicates both of them take almost the same time for execution.

My graphs:

[image: First trial]

[image: second trial]

my code:

```
import numpy
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
selection = {}
bubble = {}
while n<=10000:
    a = numpy.random.randint(low=1 , high= 100 , size= n)

    #selection sort
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n-1):
        idx = i
        for j in range(i+1 , n):
            if a[j] < a[idx]:
                idx = j
        a[i] , a[idx] = a[idx] , a[i]
    end = time.time()
    selection[n] = end-start

    #bubble sort
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(n-1-i):
            if a[j] > a[j+1]:
                a[j] , a[j+1] = a[j+1] , a[j]
    end = time.time()
    bubble[n] = end-start

    n+=1000

print(selection , bubble)            
plt.plot(selection.keys() , selection.values() , label="selectionSort")
plt.plot(bubble.keys() , bubble.values() , label="bubbleSort")
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("time")
plt.show()
```

Can anyone help me understand this abomination?

Edit: problem was I was giving sorted array to bubble sort

New graph for the record:

[image]

Comment: For both insertion sort, and bubble sort the big O time complexity is O(N), also which is which in your graph? because one of them looks mildly faster.

Comment: @acornTime: O(N²)

Comment: After you do the selection sort, the array is sorted. So your bubble sort is always being run on a sorted array, which makes it faster.

Comment: Both algorithms are in `O(n²)`. The variation is ONLY for AVERAGE complexity... Which is purely gambling: it depends on how data are "luckily" placed in the original array.
So with the same randomly filled array, both algorithms shouldn't produce slightly different results... In fact, your plotting is a parabolic curve (see how tangent is raising at the end). Also, what @rici said is exact: make a copy of array `a` before sorting it for the bubble sort: add `b=a` after creating `a`, then add `a=b` before `start = time.time()` in bubble sort part. Rerun and replot, and see what you'll get.

Comment: @Wisblade: `b = a[:]`. This is Python; assignment doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Trojan, which curve is bubble / selection? Your curve labels aren't visible... Also, you didn't gave your corrected code.

Comment: @Wisblade i made new array b = a.copy() to be sorted by bubble sort. Also orange line is bubble sort and blue line is selection sort

Comment: @Trojan Thanks for the precision. As you noticed, even if selection sort is faster than bubble sort, _BOTH_ curves are parabolic - confirming the `O(n²)` complexity for both, while confirming too the lower _average_ complexity for selection sort. As planned / predicted. So your test is now pertinent.

Comment: @Wisblade i already knew that